# Javascript Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Iam trying get the location of the user and than pass it to an Weather API.i need to the location and also to get the API data and insert the location to API url as a coordinates. this is my code and it isn't working :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var weatherLocal;

  var url = {
    "apiKey": "&appid=API_KEY",
    "api": "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=",
    "units": "&units=metric",
  }; 

  function geoLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback);
    }else  {
        console.log("not avialable");
    }
  } 

  function successCallback(position) {
    url.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    url.lon = position.coords.longitude;    
  }

  function preLoader() {
    var u = successCallback();
    var apiUrl = url.api + u + url.apiKey + url.units;
    $.getJSON(apiUrl, getData);
    console.log(apiUrl);
  }

  function getData(data) {
    weatherLocal = data;
    console.log("the longitude is " + weatherLocal.coord.lon + " and the latitude is " + weatherLocal.coord.lat + " and the description is " + weatherLocal.weather[0].main + " and the city is " + weatherLocal.name + " temperature is " + weatherLocal.main.temp);
  }

  preLoader();
});
```

Comment: Which part isn't working?Are you getting the location part right?

Comment: yes but the url is not working it just saying u is undefined

Comment: What is `successCallback()`?

Comment: it the callbak of the geoLocation function

Comment: There is no such function [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_geolocation.htm) or any of the documentations.If you have defined it, where is the body?

Comment: @SatejS the geolocation function i call the getCurrentPositon() method so successCallback() is the callback of the this method

Comment: `var u = successCallback();` calls the function with no parameters, it is bound to be undefined.I think you are expecting the earlier function call values to retain the position.

Comment: @SatejS yes , so what is the solution

Comment: Why are you using  `u`?Simply use the `url.lat` and `url.lon`

Comment: i have tried it is not working

Comment: i have tried another way

Comment: You're welcome,what did you do?

Comment: i found another API which is more easier than the geolocation and this is the link [link](http://ipinfo.io) .